# How to replicate this text effect? Skew? Arch? Bulge?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, skew, distort

I need help on how to create this text effect in Illustrator CS6.
The free transform is not working, the bulge, envelope, and arch are not giving the same effect.[image]

Comment: Having grown up there, that's a really misshapen langlade county. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy solution to this. The text is quite distorted and it uses a couple different distortions.

I got close by setting an **Envelope** to **bulge** at 18%. Then draw a **no-fill, no-stroke rectangle** in the middle of the envelope and group it with the envelope. Now apply a second **Envelope** set to **Arch** at 30%. This gets somewhat close.

The no-fill, no-stroke rectangle and group is used so you can apply two envelopes. The rectangle won't alter reproduction or output in *any way*, but it allows the grouping and then the second envelope.

From there, it's a matter of using **Free Transform** and distorting some corners by dragging them outward to better fit the shape. And a little skewing. There's no method I could share which would be a definitive answer as to what settings to use for these alteration. It's a matter of trial and error.

[image]

I didn't concern myself with font matching beyond using a serif typeface.